# How can I make sure distillery includes Erlang inets in the release?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, distillery

My application, when trying to run a release, has this fatal issue:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:inets, {'no such file or directory', 'inets.app'}}}
```

It works fine when running it with `mix` on my localhost, however the distillery 2 release has this issue.

I installed `erlang-inets` ubuntu package from the erlang solutions repo and did another `mix release`, but that didn't seem to fix it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instruct `mix` to include `inets` OTP application into the release. In your `mix.exs`:

```
def application do
  [
    mod: {MyApp, []},
    ...
    applications: [:logger, ..., :inets, ...]
  ]
end
```

*Sidenote*: `erlang-inets` has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: what is the erlang-inets package for then?

Comment: I worked out that it's getting stuck due to jose not compiling, trying to figure it out (question submitted here https://github.com/potatosalad/erlang-jose/issues/68)

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this on a freshly-generated Phoenix 1.7 project, but it was a symptom of trying to run a `dev` release, when really I should have produced a `prod` release:

```bash
MIX_ENV=prod mix release
```

With the production build, `:inets` was not required.