# Rebar3 Docker "Rebar dependency inets could not be loaded for reason no such file"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, erlang, elixir, rebar3

I was trying to setup Dockerfile for my application but this application also creates some Erlang scripts at runtime with Rebar3. The issue is when i execute `rebar3 new escript <name>` at runtime, it gives me following error:

> <<"===> Rebar dependency inets could not be loaded for reason {"no
> such file or directory",\n
> "inets.app"}\n">>

This is the current part of the Dockerfile (Elixir image is based on Erlang image):

```
FROM docker.io/elixir:1.14

# Prepare Mix
RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix local.rebar --force

# Copy Release
COPY --from=builder /app/_build/prod/rel/example /release/example

ENTRYPOINT [ "/release/example/bin/example" ]
```

I tried installing `erlang-dev`, `erlang-inets` etc... And they didn't work.

Comment: What's the second line of that error message?

Comment: There are no other output.

Comment: @legoscia, You need to scroll all the way to the right to see the end of the error message. Edit: I edited the op's post, so that you can see the whole error message.

Comment: A wild guess at what the problem might be: the release is built with `dev_mode` set to `true`, meaning that `/app/_build/prod/lib` contains symlinks instead of actual copies of the libraries. Try setting `dev_mode` to `false` - see examples on [this page](https://adoptingerlang.org/docs/production/releases/).

Comment: @legoscia, This error is from rebar3 itself, not any app. View detailed issue here: https://github.com/erlang/rebar3/issues/2789

Comment: Actually adding `inets` to app.src solved the issue but i have zero idea about how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make sure distillery includes Erlang inets in the release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55100363/how-can-i-make-sure-distillery-includes-erlang-inets-in-the-release)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip no, somehow `erlang:open_port` and my application looks like related. I just need to use `rebar3` globally with capturing it is informations realtime.